# How to parse an array of strings in flutter?

Tags: http, parsing, flutter

I need to parse an array of strings that is not necessarily valid JSON.

I am using the HTTP client and getting back the following response body from the API. How would I do this in flutter?

```
[
"Feb 22, 2019 20:16:04 UTC - TestProperty, Elevator 1001: The monitoring device on the elevator experienced a power loss and just restarted.",
"Feb 22, 2019 20:12:56 UTC - TestProperty, Elevator 1001: The monitoring device on the elevator experienced a power loss and just restarted.",
"Feb 22, 2019 19:20:33 UTC - TestProperty, Elevator 1001: The monitoring device on the elevator experienced a power loss and just restarted.",
"Feb 22, 2019 19:17:46 UTC - TestProperty, Elevator 1003: The monitoring device on the elevator experienced a power loss and just restarted.",
"Feb 22, 2019 18:35:36 UTC - TestProperty, Elevator 1001: The monitoring device on the elevator experienced a power loss and just restarted.",
"Feb 22, 2019 18:34:59 UTC - TestProperty, Elevator 1001: The monitoring device on the elevator experienced a power loss and just restarted.",
"Feb 22, 2019 18:34:59 UTC - TestProperty, Elevator 1001: The monitoring device on the elevator experienced a power loss and just restarted.",
"Feb 22, 2019 03:02:08 UTC - TestProperty, Elevator 1001: LiftAI is continuing to watch for any activity on this elevator, nothing during the past 15 minutes",
"Feb 22, 2019 02:47:04 UTC - TestProperty, Elevator 1001: LiftAI is continuing to watch for any activity on this elevator, nothing during the past 15 minutes",
"Feb 22, 2019 02:31:59 UTC - TestProperty, Elevator 1001: LiftAI is continuing to watch for any activity on this elevator, nothing during the past 15 minutes",
"Feb 22, 2019 02:16:54 UTC - TestProperty, Elevator 1001: LiftAI is continuing to watch for any activity on this elevator, nothing during the past 15 minutes",
"Feb 22, 2019 02:01:49 UTC - TestProperty, Elevator 1001: LiftAI is continuing to watch for any activity on this elevator, nothing during the past 15 minutes",
"Feb 22, 2019 01:46:44 UTC - TestProperty, Elevator 1001: LiftAI is continuing to watch for any activity on this elevator, nothing during the past 15 minutes",
"Feb 22, 2019 01:31:39 UTC - TestProperty, Elevator 1001: LiftAI is continuing to watch for any activity on this elevator, nothing during the past 15 minutes",
"Feb 22, 2019 01:16:34 UTC - TestProperty, Elevator 1001: Elevator just ended a trip up with a duration of 8 seconds",
"Feb 22, 2019 01:14:47 UTC - TestProperty, Elevator 1001: LiftAI is now watching the elevator, which has never recorded a trip",
"Feb 22, 2019 01:11:33 UTC - TestProperty, Elevator 1001: LiftAI is now watching the elevator, which has never recorded a trip"
]
```

Comment: I assume you don't have control over backend? Can you explain why the response is not necessarily valid JSON? Is it something like single quote vs double quote, trailing comma etc?

Answer (score 0):

This was a silly question. Someone on reddit mentioned that an array of strings is valid JSON. The following snippet shows how to convert the response to a list of strings and then instantiate a list of another type.

```
  static List<LiftNotification> parseProperties(String responseBody) {
    List<String> notifications = json.decode(responseBody).cast<String>();
    return notifications.map<LiftNotification>((notification) => new LiftNotification(name: notification)).toList();
  }
```